# How to store as a comma separated list of values stored in a string, in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0

I have a string called joined which contains a range of values as a comma separated list.

For example when I print joined the output is as follows.

```
59.05,59.00,58.96,58.95,58.95,58.95,58.95,58.96,60.30,61.32
```

What I want to know is, how can I store this sting variable in SQL Server. I want to store it as it is, so that my database won't grow unnecessarily.

Can you please be kind enough to give me a piece of code showing how to do this.

Comment: You can create a `NVARCHAR(max)` fields in SQL server to save that or Split your output string by ',' separator to a String[] array! For example: `String.Split(outputStr, ',')`

Comment: 99.999% of the cases, This is a very bad idea. Also, it will not save you any storage space since you must use varchar for that instead of a simple int column.

Comment: It's far better to store the data in a data type *designed* for holding multiple values (e.g. `xml` or, indeed, rows of a table). You're just setting yourself up for issues by cramming all of your data into an opaque string that then can't be easily queried against.

Comment: Does the database need to have any interaction with these values? does your program use them as separate values? If the answer to one of this questions is yes, then you should store them as separate values and not as a comma delimited string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a comma separated string in .net then you can pass it directly to column value. But please make sure that your column length have sufficient enough to store whole string otherwise it will truncated. Using varchar(max) will be good for column data type.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Joined", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Joined.Text;
```

To save space we can use Varchar instead of Nvarchar.

Comment: No, it's not. if the string only contains numbers and commas, it should be varchar(max), that is half the storage space. However, as I wrote in the comment to the question itself, this is a bad idea to begin with. In 16 years of programming I've only found one scenario where storing comma delimited values inside a database table was the correct solution.

Comment: Totaly agree with Zohar. Its not good practise to store comma separated value in column. But user2766227 may have some scenario so if he can use mentioned way.